# Simular um click do mouse usando X11

Tags: ubuntu, interface, c++11, linux, eventos-do-mouse

Estou tentando simular um click do mouse usando a biblioteca X11 no linux.
Usando o comando `xev` no terminal tenho as seguintes saidas.

Para um click real:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
root 0xdb, subw 0x0, time 1776350, (302,342), root:(306,365),
state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
root 0xdb, subw 0x0, time 1776470, (302,342), root:(306,365),
state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES
```

Para o click simulado:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic YES, window 0x2c00001,
root 0xdb, subw 0x0, time 0, (302,342), root:(306,365),
state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic YES, window 0x2c00001,
root 0xdb, subw 0x0, time 0, (302,342), root:(306,365),
state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES
```

O problema é que o click não acontece, o evento aparece mas o mouse não clica. Estou deixando o código abaixo, realmente não acho onde pode ser o problema.

```
void MouseClick(int button)
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    // Create and setting up the event
    XEvent event;
    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    event.xbutton.button = button;
    event.xbutton.same_screen = True;
    event.xbutton.subwindow = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    while (event.xbutton.subwindow)
    {
        event.xbutton.window = event.xbutton.subwindow;
        XQueryPointer(display, event.xbutton.window,
                      &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.subwindow,
                      &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root,
                      &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y,
                      &event.xbutton.state);
    }
    // Press
    event.type = ButtonPress;
    if (XSendEvent(display, PointerWindow, True, ButtonPressMask, &event) == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error to send the event!\n");
    XFlush(display);
    usleep(1);
    // Release
    event.type = ButtonRelease;
    if (XSendEvent(display, PointerWindow, True, ButtonReleaseMask, &event) == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error to send the event!\n");
    XFlush(display);
    usleep(1);

    XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```